# Jmeter JDBC request result need to filter and store into variables

Tags: jmeter

I have JDBC request which is providing results see below example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtxTs.png)

My requerment is how to filter JDBC result and store in variables?

1. Filter how many records status as A
2. Filter how many records status as A & I
3. Filter how many records status as D
   I need store in variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're showing us some form of a CSV file, JMeter doesn't handle JDBC Request sampler results this way.

Depending on your "requirement" and configuration you can go for one of the following:

0. First of all it doesn't seem you need everything, you can just leave `status` column in your SQL query
1. Use 3 SQL statements with [COUNT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count.asp) functions
2. Declare either each column or just `status` as

   [image]

   once done you will have the following variables:

   ```
   status_1=A
   status_2=A
   status_3=A
   status_4=D
   status_5=D
   etc.
   ```

   and then you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to count the occurrences with [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) , for example:

   ```
   def statuses = []

   1.upto(vars.get('status_#') as int, {
       statuses.add(vars.get('status_' + it))
   })

   vars.put('A', statuses.count('A') as String)
   vars.put('A&I', statuses.findAll { status -> status == 'A' || status == 'I' }.size() as String)
   vars.put('D', statuses.count('D') as String)
   ```
3. If you use "Result variable name" you need to write a little bit more complex code.